# Load html from resources file to QTextEdit

Tags: qt

I am trying to do as follows:

```
QWidget* helpWidget = new QWidget();
QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout();
QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit();
textEdit->loadResource(QTextDocument::HtmlResource, QUrl("qrc:/help.html"));
textEdit->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
layout->addWidget(textEdit);
helpWidget->setLayout(layout);
```

The resource file is as follows:

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file alias="help.html">../doc/index.html</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

However the html file does not display in the QTextView. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`QTextEdit::loadResource`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#loadResource) is a virtual method intended for a different purpose, [see docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#loadResource).

Instead you should manually read and set the HTML file contents:

```
QFile file(":/help.html");
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);
QTextStream stream(&file);
textEdit->setHtml(stream.readAll());
```